# How to fix 'Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I have a modal window for Logging.
When I press submit, I am logging, but the result I can see after reloading page manually

I open function  after_sign_in_path_for(resource) and add line
redirect_to root_path and return true

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: 
  :devise_controller?
    before_action :set_referral_cookie
    before_action :blog_redirect
    force_ssl unless: :ssl_configured?
  #   skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    before_action :redirect_logins

    def redirect_logins 
      if request.fullpath.match('users/sign_in') && request.get?
        redirect_to '/?sign_in=true'
      end
    end

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      redirect_to root_path
      '/'
    end

    def ssl_configured?
      puts request.original_url
      Rails.env.development? || !!request.original_url.match('/blog')
    end

    def blog
      redirect_to "https://www.xxx.xx/blog#{request.fullpath.gsub('/blog','')}", :status => :moved_permanently
     end
```

In the console, I got a message

Redirected to http://localhost:3090/
   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 755ms (ActiveRecord: 491.9ms)

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were 
  called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only 
  call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that 
  neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if 
  you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do 
  something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):
```

Comment: I think that when you click on the submit button, you are still on the `users/sign_in` path, so your `redirect_logins` callback is called in addition to the `after_sign_in_path`

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about the syntax but the concept here is:
`redirect_to` does not stop the execution of the action method so if you call it and later call render or another `redirect_to` you will get the double render exception. There is a fairly simple fix, just call and return. e.g.

```
redirect_to root_path and return
```

See 'Avoiding double render exceptions' in the [Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors).

Answer (score 0):

default devise will redirect to after_sign_in_path_for(resource), so
`after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` must be return path 
in this case, it should be

```rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  root_path
end
```

or

```rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  '\'
end
```

root cause is `redirect_to` inside this method, you have 2 times redirect to, so we have this error

Comment: what is the place redirect_to before after_sign_in_path_for(resource) ?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L23
you can see option param `location`, it have to redirect to  
 `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`